# Extension Development Host window in vscode is not showing my extension in activity bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, visual-studio-code-debugging

The problem I am facing is that my Visual Studio Code extension is not appearing in the Activity Bar of the Extension Development Host window. Despite correctly defining a view container and views in the `package.json` file, the extension fails to show up in the Activity Bar, hindering users from accessing its functionality easily.

This is the `package.json` file that I am using for my extension.

```json
"contributes": {
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "package-explorer",
          "title": "Package Explorer",
          "icon": "assets/icon.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "package-explorer": [
        {
          "id": "package-dependencies",
          "name": "Dependencies"
        },
        {
          "id": "package-outline",
          "name": "Outline"
        }
      ]
    },
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "cell-notifier.activate",
        "title": "Activate Cell Notifier"
      }
    ]
  },
```

When I run my extension using the debugger, a new Extension Development Host Visual Studio Code window opens, but my extension is not shown in the activity bar.

[image]

My extension has activated, and is shown in the page of the `Developer: Show Running Extensions` command

Comment: where are your other Activity Bar icons: Search, SCM, Extensions, Debug

Comment: do you have logic/code that adds a view to that Bar

Comment: does the VSC example work for new Activity Bar Views

Comment: I have hidden all of those activity bar icons, just for the screenshot.

Comment: For the extension that is being build by me, I am not able to view the extension on activity bar in extension development  host window in vscode. Can you please help me out with it.

Comment: I have added only the package.json, is there any other logic to add apart from it

Comment: why would you show a bar that has no view inside, a view needs JS logic to show something

Comment: Can you please do share the reference resource link for it. Thankyou

Comment: Is the `package-explorer` icon showing up in the Activity Bar?  And do you have `assets/icon.png` in your extension?